# chrome 82 - hide input type time "clock" symbol

Tags: html, input

starting chrome 81 or 82, the input type time has a clock symbol to its right - how can I hide it (input should still be editable, so not readonly)?

Comment: I was facing this problem too. I found the solution here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61934417/10978732)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit the icon by this selector:

```
// normal
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator

// focus
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator:focus
```

So, for hide the icon:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```