# Hide the icon on a HTML time input field in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome when you `type="time"` property to an input box you get a little icon clock icon next to the input. Is there a way of removing this little clock icon?

Comment: I'm not seeing this. Can you screenshot what you mean?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Based on the answers to this question:
[Change date input triangle to a calendar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436074/change-date-input-triangle-to-a-calendar-icon)

We can see that we need to override the -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator pseudo-element, for example:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: none;
}
```

Here it is in Chrome by default

[image: Default time picker]

Here it is with -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator background none

[image: Background none picker]

Of course you're hiding the fact there is a clickable picker so you may well want to think again about how you're displaying this if it's read only or do some more styling.

And to pull in Eiriks useful contribution from below, to remove the space completely add:

```
display:none;
```

Comment: `input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { background: none; display:none;
}`
removes the space too.

Comment: For input date => `input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:auto
```

This solution enables clicking input field and popup the time picker.