# <input type="time"> auto close when seconds or minutes is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I want it to close automatically when I select 'seconds' or 'minutes' in the `<input type="time">`

click on an empty place to close it (chrome browser)

attempted with 'input' event but could not detect what was selected

AM or PM > Hours > Minutes
Auto close if the last selection was 'Minutes'

AM or PM > hour > minute > second
Auto close if the last selection was 'seconds'

```html
<input type="time">
```

[image]

attempted with 'input' event but could not detect what was selected

Comment: I think it's best to leave browser specific popups as they are. You can possibly [style them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker), but the user interaction is fully handled by the browser and specific to chrome only.

Comment: The only approach I can think of for closing that popover is removing focus from the input, and that comes with all sorts of UX issues. As mentioned above, built in browser UI is generally not easy to change and may vary from user to user (E.g. I see a slightly different popup due to my language/time settings)

Comment: The whole point of using browser/platform specific widgets is to abstract these details away. Firefox on Linux, for example, does not even have a popup selector. Even if you make it work for Chrome, you risk making it annoying. What's the ultimate goal? I suspect there may be a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: i also think so it's right to leave browser-specific popups alone. 
But my bosses and clients don't like the trivial behavior of clicking on empty places on the screen ;-(

Comment: Oh, they're just being awkward.  It was a choice by Chrome to make it work this way, ask them to switch to Firefox, it doesn't have a popup. Alternatively, if they don't click on the clock icon, the popup won't appear and they can just enter the time normally.

Comment: Oh, how about [hiding the clock icon altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934148/hide-the-icon-on-a-html-time-input-field-in-chrome)? using `input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { background: none; display:none; }`, that way the input behaves the same as in Firefox.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm thinking of using input type="text" and the list attribute to assist with the hour/minute/second input. It's a bit messy, but I think it's better than select tag.