# How do I keep the same time input style in both firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, browser, angular-material, mozilla

How do I keep the same time input style in both firefox and chrome. I want it like in firefox. I am using angular material

firefox input time:

[image]

chrome input time:

[image]

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label>Hora hasta</mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="time" name="d4" [(ngModel)]="updateModel.horaHasta[0]" [min]="minHour" max="23:59">
                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: See here to hide the clock icon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934148/hide-the-icon-on-a-html-time-input-field-in-chrome

Comment: For any other issues, research each one in turn.

Comment: Do you have something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in your project?

Comment: @GetSet yes but still remain the height of the input

Comment: @iburakov no, im using angular material